# --preserve_ascii_control_characters not working in bq load command line

Tags: bq

I am trying to load the data into BQ using bq load command line with the argument '--preserve_ascii_control_characters=true' . First few lines are given here

bq load 
--source_format=CSV 
--preserve_ascii_control_characters=true \

But I keep getting below error. It is working fine if I do not pass this argument. What could be the issue?

FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'preserve_ascii_control_characters'